# mysql min with where clause optimization

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index-tuning, explain

I want to get min user_id for a tenant_id.

mysql engine - innodb

table - `users(id, tenant_id, is_deleted, creation_date)`

pk `(id)`

sk `(tenant_id, creation_date)`

query1 `select min(id) from users where tenant_id = 123;`

[image]

query2  `select id from users where tenant_id = 123 order by id limit 1;`

[image]

I have observed that the query1 is faster than query2. Also, If I force index on query2, then it uses filesort in addition to using index. I want to know why query1 is faster and in query2 why filesort is being used as innodb adds pk at end of sk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query. Server filters the rows by provided `tenant_id` value using the index then investigates hidden primary key expression which is a part of any index and finds minimal `id`.

Second query. Server scans the whole table (due to primary key the rows in the table body are already sorted by `id`) until specified `tenant_id` found.

The index by `(tenant_id, id)` seems to be the most efficient. - [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)